# Ansible - Variable within a lookup

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to create an IAM policy specific to the playbook being used, but each playbook uses a common role.

I have the following defined in two different playbooks:

```yaml
policy_document: "iam_policy_1.json"
```

```yaml
policy_document: "iam_policy_2.json"
```

and the corresponding IAM policy JSON files are in my templates directory for a common role.

In my tasks for the role, I have

```yaml
- name: create IAM policy
  iam_policy:
    iam_name: "{{ app_name }}"
    policy_name: "{{ app_name }}-policy"
    policy_json: "{{ lookup('template',policy_document) }}"
    iam_type: "role"
    state: "present"
```

Am I able to do `{{ lookup('template',policy_document) }}`? I am unsure of having a variable nested within a jinja2 template. Would `{{ lookup('template',{{ policy_document }}) }}` work?

Comment: Close because of `caused by typo` as claimed in the Q&A. It's not a typo at all and the code should work as expected. Anyway, close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, you **can** do this, but my spacing was incorrect. This is valid:

```yaml
policy_json: "{{ lookup('template', policy_document) }}"
```